# Handle events in a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a jQuery plugin but I'm stuck when I'm handling events.

For example I want the user to be able to specify a function to handle my save event

He would configure it like this

```
$(".foo").bar({
  save: function (x,y){
     alert("whatever");
  })
});
```

But I dont know how to call that from my plugin and how to pass arguments...

thanks for reading !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin code will look something like this:

```
$.fn.bar = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, {/*your default options*/}, options);
});
```

When you want to call the user-supplied function, call it:

```
options.save(x, y); // or whatever x and y are
```

If you want to call the function so that the variable `this` has a useful meaning within that function, use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
options.save.call(somevar, x, y);
```

This sets `this` within your callback to `somevar`.  If, for example, you wanted the callback to have the selection that `bar` was called on, you could do `options.save.call(this, x y);`

Comment: Nice explanation, but you'll want to flip the positions of the `options` and the `defaults` in the `$.extend`. :o)

Comment: @patrick Good catch -- I was busy trying to decide whether to make up any options to put in there and completely forgot what order they went in.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bar = function( opts ) {
          // reference the function from the options passed
        var theFunc = opts.save;
          // call the function
        theFunc();
         // or call the function from the context of the jQuery object
         //    and pass it the proper arguments
        theFunc.call( this, 'someX', 'someY' );
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.bar = function(options) {

        // Extend default config with config object passed at invocation time
        options = $.extend({
             ...

        }, options);

        // Check that Callback function has been passed
        if (options.save) {

             var newVar = ...;

             // Delegate the function to some variable (it will act as *this* in the called 
             // function). You can pass few arguments as well
             options.save.call(newVar, arg1, arg2)
        } 

    };
})(jQuery);
```